# How to delete one-to-one relating models cascading in django?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, orm, model

#### Background:

I have the below models defined in Django(1.8.5):

```
class PublishInfo(models.Model):
    pass

class Book(models.Model):
    info = models.OneToOneField(
        PublishInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Newspaper(models.Model):
    info = models.OneToOneField(
        PublishInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Where Book and `NewsPaper` shares a same model `PublishInfo` as a `OneToOneField`, which is in fact a unique foreign key.

Now, if I delete a `PublishInfo` Object, the relating `Book` or `Newspaper` object is deleted with cascading.

---

#### Question:

But in fact, I want to delete the `PublishInfo` object cascading when I delete the `Book` or `Newspaper` object. This way is the way I may call.

Is there any good way to automatically cascading the deletion in the reverse direction in this case? And, if yes, could it be explained?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You attach [`post_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-delete) signal to your model so it is called upon deletion of an instance of `Book` or `Newspaper`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Book)
def auto_delete_publish_info_with_book(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.info.delete()

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Newspaper)
def auto_delete_publish_info_with_newpaper(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.info.delete()
```

Comment: Good, I think this method is suitable and do not introduce much mode.

Comment: But some problem: when I delete a queryset, it cannot be cascade, have some solution for this case? or just prevent to do batch delete?

Comment: For batch insertion and deletion, these kind of signals are not sent. So, yes I think cheapest way is to delete one by one. Also, you might want to subclass queryset class for your models and override `delete` method if you want to have the same behavior for batch updates.

Comment: I found an even nicer solution, have a look.

Answer (score 7):

#### Another straight forward solution by overriding `save` and `delete` method:

Comparing to the answer of @ozgur, I found using signal to cascading the delete action has the same effect as deleting by overriding the `Model.delete()` method, and also we might auto create the attached `PublishInfo`:

```
class Book(models.Model):

    info = models.OneToOneField(
        PublishInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.info:
            self.info = Publish.objects.create()
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.info:
            self.info.delete()
```

---

#### More structured and reusable solution:

So, soon I realized the three listing field and methods are obviously redundant on each Model which was attaching the `PublishInfo` models as a field.

So, why don't we use inheritance?

```
class PublishInfoAttachedModel(models.Model):

    info = models.OneToOneField(
        PublishInfo, related_name='$(class)s',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.info:
            self.info = Publish.objects.create()
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.info:
            self.info.delete()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Remember to add `abstract = True` in its meta class.

So, now we are free to add `PublishInfo` in any other models we want to attach that model, and we can make more than one such abstract models:

```
class Book(PublishInfoAttachedModel, 
           models.Model):
    pass

class NewsPaper(PublishInfoAttachedModel, 
           CommentsAttachedModel,  # if we have other attached model info
           models.Model):
    pass
```

Notice the `models.Model` class in the trailing super class list can be ignored, I wrote this is just to make the classes more obvious as a `Model`.