# How to cascade delete on one to one both sides in django?

Tags: django

I have the models set as follows:

```
class CodeConstraint(models.Model):
    must_not_have = models.TextField()


class Question(models.Model):
    code_constraint = models.OneToOneField(CodeConstraint, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

When i delete CodeConstraint the associated Question will be deleted. I would like the cascade to go the other way as well i.e when i delete Question the associated CodeConstraint should also be deleted. How do i achieve this behavior? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: One quick approach could be setting `OneToOneField` in `CodeConstraint`?

Comment: See this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205392/how-to-delete-one-to-one-relating-models-cascading-in-django

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a signal for that. Something that goes like this

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Question)
def delete_code_constraint_with_question(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.code_constraint.delete()
```

Much better if you add some error handling

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override the `delete()` function?

Maybe you could do something like this:

```py
# in your model

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        one_to_one_obj.delete()
        super(modelName, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```